# What is the incident power of the sun for different parts of the U.S over time?

Tags: energy, radiation, sun

I have seen number as low as $200\ \text{W}/\text{m}^2$ to $1000 \text{W}/\text{m}^2$.

I'm in California and looking for information on how much power my solar panels will pick up.

I have $4100\ \text{W}$ panels.

I can get the efficiency of the panels from the manufacturer but I need to know what I'm starting with.

Assume a clear day.  Obviously it will vary with the date ( distance from the sun ) and geographical location ( same ), assume California.

Assume I am at ground level.  Any kind of graph / chart would be useful.

I was boggled at all the stuff Google pulled up that was not relevant for someone trying to do simple ground level calculations for a few solar panels.

[These guys](https://ag.tennessee.edu/solar/Pages/What%20Is%20Solar%20Energy/Sun%27s%20Energy.aspx) state $1000\ \text{W}/\text{m}^2$

[These guys](http://zebu.uoregon.edu/disted/ph162/l4.html) state $300\text{W}/\text{m}^2$ to $600\text{W}/\text{m}^2$ depending upon location and weather.

Given a clear day and no other information (location, season, etc.), should I assume $500\text{W}/\text{m}^2$?

Probably best to get a meter and just measure it.

[These guys](https://ag.tennessee.edu/solar/Pages/What%20Is%20Solar%20Energy/Sun%27s%20Energy.aspx) state $1000\ \text{W}/\text{m}^2$

Comment: This is both very latitude-dependent (i.e. more sensitive than "assume California", which spans 10 degrees of latitude) and very weather-dependent, which is why you see such variation.

Comment: You might get the most useful feeling of it at your exact location by Googling for a a [solar irradiance](https://www.google.dk/search?q=solar+irradiance+map&rlz=1C1GCEA_enDK817DK817&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJw6vYoojfAhUClosKHU67CLcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=1058#imgrc=YvQs07cR7T0VCM:) map of the planet or of your continent.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic answer is 1000 W/m^2. The reason you see lower values is that they are covered by cloud, etc.

But the question you really want to ask is "how can I calculate how much power my panels will produce?"

The answer is "[you use this calculator](https://pvwatts.nrel.gov/)". Just follow the prompts and you'll get everything you need, including average insolation.